# Programmatically allow @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a controller with `@RequestMapping`, but I want to enable this controller mapping only when some conditions are met (eg. some database value or other application condition allows it). Is it possible by some simple way to activate/deactivate whole `@RequestMapping` for example based on checking some method like `isMapppingAllowed()` from `mappingController` Spring bean? Is it possible to even activate/deactivate at runtime when the context is already loaded?

Comment: Can't you just do it inside the controller?

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand yes, but this controller has 10+ methods and I those methods can be (and will be) added with each new version. So I am looking for some better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things, the second being a more direct answer to your question.

1) Process the request, get the data you need to check if it is allowed, and then continue processing/reject the request in the controller code, and redirect it as necessary.

2) Add a custom filter, or maybe look into spring security if it is for authentication purposes.

Comment: I am already using spring security and the methods are protected. But as an another level of protection I want to explicitelly disallow listening ... EDIT: I will try custom filter, but does not Spring support it better/simplier way ?

Comment: I would build it into the authentication filter based on some role you define to access that controller's methods, whereas other roles would be unable to access those methods

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I will just redirect all requests somewhere else if on my instance is not allowed to use this controller at all. Thanks for hint about filters - I was too wrapped up on Controller and tryed to solve it with them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, if you want your controller not to do anything on certain conditions work that lógic inside  of it, would you rather see a 404 or a detailed error when you load a page?

Comment: In this case 404 or rather rejecting communication, both will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write Interceptor or filter,because in both you get request object,so you can check the URL and accordingly,can apply your mapping rules.

Comment: thanks, interceptor will probably suit more better in my use case